# Extract a JS object as JSON

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json, regex

https://www.genenames.org/js/custom-downloads-bf.js

The above URL contains an object like this.

I would like to extract it print it to stdout in JSON format. Could anybody show me the complete code (in python or nodejs) to achieve this goal?

```
        var i = {
            CHROMOSOMES: {
                HUMAN: [{
                    name: "1",
                    value: "1"
                }, {
                    name: "2",
                    value: "2"
                }, {
                    name: "3",
                    value: "3"
                }, {
                    name: "4",
                    value: "4"
                }, {
                    name: "5",
                    value: "5"
                }, {
                    name: "6",
                    value: "6"
                }, {
                    name: "7",
                    value: "7"
                }, {
                    name: "8",
                    value: "8"
                }, {
                    name: "9",
                    value: "9"
                }, {
                    name: "10",
                    value: "10"
                }, {
                    name: "11",
                    value: "11"
                }, {
                    name: "12",
                    value: "12"
                }, {
                    name: "13",
                    value: "13"
                }, {
                    name: "14",
                    value: "14"
                }, {
                    name: "15",
                    value: "15"
                }, {
                    name: "16",
                    value: "16"
                }, {
                    name: "17",
                    value: "17"
                }, {
                    name: "18",
                    value: "18"
                }, {
                    name: "19",
                    value: "19"
                }, {
                    name: "20",
                    value: "20"
                }, {
                    name: "21",
                    value: "21"
                }, {
                    name: "22",
                    value: "22"
                }, {
                    name: "X",
                    value: "X"
                }, {
                    name: "Y",
                    value: "Y"
                }, {
                    name: "reserved loci",
                    value: "reserved"
                }, {
                    name: "mitochondrial",
                    value: "mito"
                }, {
                    name: "pseudoautosomal",
                    value: "XandY"
                }]
            },
            STATUSES: [{
                name: "Approved",
                value: "Approved"
            }, {
                name: "Entry and symbol withdrawn",
                value: "Entry Withdrawn"
            }],
            ATTRIBUTES: {
                HGNC: [{
                    name: "HGNC ID",
                    value: "gd_hgnc_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Approved symbol",
                    value: "gd_app_sym"
                }, {
                    name: "Approved name",
                    value: "gd_app_name"
                }, {
                    name: "Status",
                    value: "gd_status"
                }, {
                    name: "Locus type",
                    value: "gd_locus_type"
                }, {
                    name: "Locus group",
                    value: "gd_locus_group"
                }, {
                    name: "Previous symbols",
                    value: "gd_prev_sym"
                }, {
                    name: "Previous name",
                    value: "gd_prev_name"
                }, {
                    name: "Synonyms",
                    value: "gd_aliases"
                }, {
                    name: "Name synonyms",
                    value: "gd_name_aliases"
                }, {
                    name: "Chromosome",
                    value: "gd_pub_chrom_map"
                }, {
                    name: "Date approved",
                    value: "gd_date2app_or_res"
                }, {
                    name: "Date modified",
                    value: "gd_date_mod"
                }, {
                    name: "Date symbol changed",
                    value: "gd_date_sym_change"
                }, {
                    name: "Date name changed",
                    value: "gd_date_name_change"
                }, {
                    name: "Accession numbers",
                    value: "gd_pub_acc_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "Enzyme IDs",
                    value: "gd_enz_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "NCBI Gene ID",
                    value: "gd_pub_eg_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Ensembl gene ID",
                    value: "gd_pub_ensembl_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Mouse genome database ID",
                    value: "gd_mgd_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Specialist database links",
                    value: "gd_other_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "Specialist database IDs",
                    value: "gd_other_ids_list"
                }, {
                    name: "Pubmed IDs",
                    value: "gd_pubmed_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "RefSeq IDs",
                    value: "gd_pub_refseq_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "Gene group ID",
                    value: "family.id"
                }, {
                    name: "Gene group name",
                    value: "family.name"
                }, {
                    name: "CCDS IDs",
                    value: "gd_ccds_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "Vega IDs",
                    value: "gd_vega_ids"
                }, {
                    name: "Locus specific databases",
                    value: "gd_lsdb_links"
                }],
                EXTERNAL: [{
                    name: "NCBI Gene ID",
                    source: "NCBI",
                    value: "md_eg_id"
                }, {
                    name: "OMIM ID",
                    source: "OMIM",
                    value: "md_mim_id"
                }, {
                    name: "RefSeq",
                    source: "NCBI",
                    value: "md_refseq_id"
                }, {
                    name: "UniProt ID",
                    source: "UniProt",
                    value: "md_prot_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Ensembl ID",
                    source: "Ensembl",
                    value: "md_ensembl_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Vega ID",
                    source: "Vega",
                    value: "md_vega_id"
                }, {
                    name: "UCSC ID",
                    source: "UCSC",
                    value: "md_ucsc_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Mouse genome database ID",
                    source: "MGI",
                    value: "md_mgd_id"
                }, {
                    name: "Rat genome database ID",
                    source: "RGD",
                    value: "md_rgd_id"
                }, {
                    name: "LNCipedia",
                    source: "LNCipedia",
                    value: "md_lncipedia"
                }, {
                    name: "GtRNAdb",
                    source: "GtRNAdb",
                    value: "md_gtrnadb"
                }]
            },
            ORDER_BY: [{
                name: "HGNC ID",
                value: "gd_hgnc_id"
            }, {
                name: "Approved symbol",
                value: "gd_app_sym_sort"
            }, {
                name: "Approved name",
                value: "gd_app_name"
            }, {
                name: "Status",
                value: "gd_status"
            }, {
                name: "Locus type",
                value: "gd_locus_type"
            }, {
                name: "Locus group",
                value: "gd_locus_group"
            }, {
                name: "Previous symbols",
                value: "gd_prev_sym"
            }, {
                name: "Previous name",
                value: "gd_prev_name"
            }, {
                name: "Synonyms",
                value: "gd_aliases"
            }, {
                name: "Name synonyms",
                value: "gd_name_aliases"
            }, {
                name: "Chromosome",
                value: "gd_pub_chrom_map_sort"
            }, {
                name: "Date approved",
                value: "gd_date2app_or_res"
            }, {
                name: "Date modified",
                value: "gd_date_mod"
            }, {
                name: "Date symbol changed",
                value: "gd_date_sym_change"
            }, {
                name: "Date name changed",
                value: "gd_date_name_change"
            }, {
                name: "Accession numbers",
                value: "gd_pub_acc_ids"
            }, {
                name: "Enzyme IDs",
                value: "gd_enz_ids"
            }, {
                name: "NCBI Gene ID",
                value: "gd_pub_eg_id"
            }, {
                name: "Ensembl gene ID",
                value: "gd_pub_ensembl_id"
            }, {
                name: "Mouse genome database ID",
                value: "gd_mgd_id"
            }, {
                name: "Specialist database links",
                value: "gd_other_ids"
            }, {
                name: "Specialist database IDs",
                value: "gd_other_ids_list"
            }, {
                name: "Pubmed IDs",
                value: "gd_pubmed_ids"
            }, {
                name: "RefSeq IDs",
                value: "gd_pub_refseq_ids"
            }, {
                name: "Gene group ID",
                value: "family.id"
            }, {
                name: "Gene group name",
                value: "family.name"
            }, {
                name: "CCDS IDs",
                value: "gd_ccds_ids"
            }, {
                name: "Vega IDs",
                value: "gd_vega_ids"
            }, {
                name: "Locus specific databases",
                value: "gd_lsdb_links"
            }, {
                name: "NCBI Gene ID (supplied by NCBI)",
                value: "md_eg_id"
            }, {
                name: "OMIM ID (supplied by OMIM)",
                value: "md_mim_id"
            }, {
                name: "RefSeq (supplied by NCBI)",
                value: "md_refseq_id"
            }, {
                name: "UniProt ID (supplied by UniProt)",
                value: "md_prot_id"
            }, {
                name: "Ensembl ID (supplied by Ensembl)",
                value: "md_ensembl_id"
            }, {
                name: "Vega ID (supplied by Vega)",
                value: "md_vega_id"
            }, {
                name: "UCSC ID (supplied by UCSC)",
                value: "md_ucsc_id"
            }, {
                name: "Mouse genome database ID (supplied by MGI)",
                value: "md_mgd_id"
            }, {
                name: "Rat genome database ID (supplied by RGD)",
                value: "md_rgd_id"
            }, {
                name: "LNCipedia ID (supplied by LNCipedia)",
                value: "md_lncipedia"
            }, {
                name: "GtRNAdb ID (supplied by GtRNAdb)",
                value: "md_gtrnadb"
            }],
            OUTPUT: ["Text", "Make URL for text"]
        };
```

Comment: The only reliable way to do this is to actually execute that code.  This is potentially dangerous if you don't trust the source.  Although I suppose you could sandbox it...

Comment: How to sandbox it? Is there a way to make a sandbox within a nodejs program to run the code?

Comment: Yes, there are a few modules for this.  Here's one:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/v8-sandbox

Comment: Do you mind making a script that works on the input custom-downloads-bf.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably prettify the .js (e.g. using  https://jsonformatter.org/jsbeautifier):

and then run it through:

```
sed -n $'/^[ \t]*CHROMOSOMES/,/^[ \t]*};/p' |
  sed -e '1s/^/{/' -e '$s/;//'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using regex to get the actual JavaScript object. However, as stated in the comments, you will need to execute the code first which could be dangerous.

```js
// NodeJS
const request = require("request");

request("https://www.genenames.org/js/custom-downloads-bf.js",(error,body,response)=>{
  const MatchedResponse = body.match(/{C.*?};/gm)[0]; //Match the Object from "{C" to "};"
  let JSONResponse;
  eval("JSONResponse = " + MatchedResponse)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONResponse));
});
```

If you are worried about malicious code being embedded in the object, you should create a function to verify the code before executing it.

Comment: But this regex doesn't seem to be very reliable. What if there some other objects from "{C" to "}"?